# TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' keeps bugging me

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Im trying to get an average on a table that I have sorted already with this

```
avg = np.average(elastic)
print ("The mean of the aluminum alloy is", avg)
```

but I'm always getting this kind of error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I tried it before and it got my desired output yesterday, but when I tried to run it again today, the TypeError pops out. I read all of the numpy documentation regarding numpy.average and tried to search but I can't find any working solution on this problem.

For more information regarding the whole code, here is what I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/m23chaffee/DS100-Repository/main/Aluminum%20Alloy%20Data%20Set.csv'
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/m23chaffee/DS100-Repository/main/Aluminum%20Alloy%20Data%20Set.csv', index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])

data #it shows the data values on jupyter notebook since the professor requires us to have seperate inlines

elastic = data[['m_elastic']]
elastic = elastic[elastic['m_elastic'].notna()]
elastic.sort_values(['m_elastic'])

avg = np.average(elastic)
print ("The mean of the aluminum alloy is", avg)
```

I tried having a float, but it doesn't work. I tried using numpy.mean, but it didn't gave me the results I wanted.

Comment: It's because `np.average` doesn't work on strings

Comment: Show `elastic`, or at least part of it.  What's its `dtype`?

Comment: What do you mean `float` "doesn't work"?   What about `np.mean`?  Isn't that the same as `np.average`?  The fact that `elastic` is a pandas DataFrame complicates the use of numpy functions.

Comment: `np.average(np.array(['1','2','three'],object))` produces this error message

Comment: @AndrzejO is there a way to like convert it to a non-string array? I'm new on working in this language and I have a lot to catch up

Comment: @LynmanAlpha You should take a look at your data. This string `10.1 - 11.6` is not a number

Comment: @AndrzejO i already make some changes on that part. does pd.DataFrame(elastic).to_numpy() is the right path?

Comment: Look at the result of the `to_numpy`.  Average needs numbers!